# Where can I find a list of SDL hotfixes and their contents?

Tags: hotfixes

When we try this page http://csei.sdl.com/hotfixes/ we see a console error when searching and nothing in the list of results:

> angular.js:11442 GET http://csei.sdl.com:8081/search?htype=c&q=sdl
>   net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I know there is an FTP containing all hotfixes but we'd have to download them all to see the README files.

My question is "where can I find a list of SDL hotfixes and their contents?"

Comment: I was able to open this link http://csei.sdl.com/hotfixes/#/hotfixes/c in chrome browser and displays a list of all the hotfixes with Full Read Me Files. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmuZ3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmuZ3.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On that page. Page works, but not always. It also doesn't work on mobile devices and maybe androids. For me Mozilla + Windows works:
[image]

Update to my answer. It seems like http://csei.sdl.com:8081/search?htype=c&q=sdl  is not accessible. This is the feed containing all hotfixes, so try to retrieve only that and use it. Maybe your VPN client is disabling it, or your connection is not secure.

Comment: Thanks. I tried Chrome, FF, IE on Mac and Windows, same problem. I wonder if you need to be authenticated at some level.

Comment: maybe, but I doubt it. you should try accessing http://csei.sdl.com:8081/search?htype=c&q=sdl  because it has all the data.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, turns out my VPN was blocking it

Comment: Great. It was probably blocked because of 8081 port